# How to insert date in sqlite through java

Tags: java, sqlite, select, date, insert

I want to make a database that will hold a date in it(SQLite).
Now first to ask is what is the right syntax to declare a date column.
The second i want to know is how to insert date in it after that. 
And the third thing i want to know is how to select dates between, for example to select  all rows which contain date between 01/05/2010 and 05/06/2010.

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need sqlite? http://hsqldb.org/ may be a more convenient for using from java.

Comment: Well i kinda want to have expirience with SQLite 'cos it is really good.

Comment: See also [Java Date - Insert into database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1081234/642706).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> *Now first to ask is what is the right syntax to declare a date column.*

From the [SQLite Data Types documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> #### 1.2 Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, [the built-in Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Take your pick. I'd go for TEXT or INTEGER. The INTEGER will be faster. If you need to store dates past 1970 (e.g. birthdates, etc), then I'd go for TEXT. If you just need to store creationtime/modificationtime, etc for now and the future, then go for INTEGER.

> *The second i want to know is how to insert date in it after that.*

Use [`PreparedStatement#setString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) or [`#setLong()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setLong%28int,%20long%29) respectively.

> *And the third thing i want to know is how to select dates between, for example to select all rows which contain date between 01/05/2010 and 05/06/2010.*

Use the standard SQL `BETWEEN` clause for this. You first need to convert the date accordingly using [the built-in date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: will this be correct sql statement:

INSERT INTO table (name, date) VALUES ("Jack", date("05/10/2010"))
and
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN date("05/10/2010") and ("05/11/2010")

and before that i created the columns name and date as a varchars.

Comment: Click the link *the built-in date and time functions*. There you'll see that a date format of `YYYY-MM-DD` is required.

Comment: So if i change the / with - all other would be correct statement?

Comment: No. You need to shuffle the dateparts as well. `YYYY` stands for years. `MM` stands for months. `DD` stands for days.

Answer (score 4):

A convenient syntax for declaring a date column is like this:

```
"CREATE TABLE "
            + "my_table"
            + "(date_time " 
            + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);");
```

This will default inserted values to the current datetime.  Or you can use **CURRENT_DATE**, or **CURRENT_TIME** values.  You won't have to insert a timestamp manually each time you create a row.

You can read about this approach here: [Android insert datetime value in SQLite database](http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-insert-datetime-value-in-sqlite-database/)

Comment: while this may not what the OP asked for, it's a better alternative for simple use cases (when you don't need to create a specific date which is not "now"). got my vote!

Comment: @Kepedizer What DID the OP ask for??