# Store date object in sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, date, jdbc

I'm using a database in my Java project and I want to store date in it, the 5th and the 6th parameter are Date Object. I used the solution below but I have errors in the indicated lines:

```
PreparedStatement creerFilm = connecteur.getConnexion().prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO FILM (ID, REF, NOM, DISTRIBUTEUR, DATEDEBUT, DATEFIN) "+
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
creerFilm.setInt(1, getId());
creerFilm.setString(2, getReference());
creerFilm.setString(3, getNomFilm());
creerFilm.setString(4, getDistributeur());
// These next two lines
creerFilm.setDate(5, new Date (getDateDebut().getDate()));
creerFilm.setDate(6, new Date (getDateFin().getDate()));
// The above two lines
creerFilm.executeUpdate();
creerFilm.close();
```

Can you help me to fix that please ?

Thank you

Comment: I thought SQLite can only store TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values for dates and times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't really tell from your code, but you have to use java.sql.Date, not java.util.Date.

Here's how you convert from a utility date instance to an SQL date instance:

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the solution you told me and I have no errors now. However I don't know which date format I should use to store it correctly in the database.


Currently I'm using a String in the constructor taht should have this format "dd-MM-yyyy", after that I use a function to convert it to SimpleDateFormat. When I use toString() everything works well but when I store it in the database I get something like that in the field "1287525600000"

Can you tell me please where is the problem exactly?

Comment: java.sql.Date has no String constructor.  The java.util.Date String constructor is depreciated.  java.text.DateFormat has a parse method that works with String dates in the format Jan 12, 1952 or January 12, 1952.  If you have a java.text.SimpleDateFormat, you have to parse it to get a java.util.Date.  Then you can use the conversion in my answer to get a java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 1):

I think detailed answer you can read here:  [How to insert date in sqlite through java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881321/how-to-insert-date-in-sqlite-through-java)

In a short, you can insert Date as **setString** (or setInt, or setLong (see the above link), but not setDate):

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(<your sql>);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
ps.setString(1, df.format(<your date>));
```