# How to insert java.util.Date in database?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to insert a date in the database, but it does not work any error message that appears. When I look at my table in Oracle DB I can not find my data that I inserted.

```
java.util.Date daterecep;
// getter and setter
public void setdaterecep( java.util.Date daterecep) {
         this.daterecep=daterecep;
} 
public  java.util.Date getdaterecep() {
       return  daterecep;
}
```

and

```
    nt val=0;
    try {
        val = st.executeUpdate("insert into tabdate (date) values('"+daterecep+"')" );
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Insertdate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println(val);
    return resultat;
}
```

I used PreparedStatement but it did not worked I just tried to execute the Java code

```
val = st.executeUpdate("insert into tabdate(date) values('12/12/2004')");
```

and add

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException {

    Insertdate B= new Insertdate();
    B.connexionBD();
    B.insert();//function for the insertion
}
```

and it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date - Insert into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081234/java-date-insert-into-database)

Answer (score 15):

Here,

```
values('"+daterecep+"')
```

you're basically attempting to store the result of `daterecep.toString()` in the database. As per the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) this is in format like as "Sat Jun 6 10:43:00 BOT 2011" (which depends on the locale and timezone!). The database does not understand it.

You should be using [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) to set a `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` field in a DB.

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into tabdate (date) values(?)" );
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(daterecep.getTime()));
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Or when it's actually a `DATE` field, use `setDate()` instead.

```
preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(daterecep.getTime()));
```

As a bonus, `PreparedStatement` also saves you from [SQL injection attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - JDBC tutorial - Using PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [Difference between `Statement` and `PreparedStatement`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement)