# JPA persist a time duration

Tags: java, jpa

I need to persist a time duration e.g. 5 d 4 h

I was thinking of using a convertion (Duration / Calendar / Date  class) where I than can persist it as a `long (millisec)` to the db (MySql).  Like that I can easily convert and work with it.

Is this a good way to do this?

Comment: This thread describes how to convert Dates to DB Date:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081234/java-date-insert-into-database

Comment: The problem isn't to persist a Date object to the db.  Hibernate in this case wille solve this and persist without a problem a Date to the DB.  I need to persist a duration.  The user will give for example a day, hours and min and this duration will be persist into the db.  As stated I would convert it to a long (as milli sec) and work with it from that.  Just wondering if that is the best way to do this.

Comment: Not all DBs could store TimePeriod. So, I doubt there's a better way. Converting to millis and storing them seems a good choice.

Comment: Just store Date with time stamp when start and store end time too..  then we can calculate... Else please post your case...At what case you want it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Hibernate 4.0 JPA provider, you can use the [Usertype project](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html) to get JPA persistence for Joda Time classes, and then use the @Type annotation.

Answer (score 1):

JodaTime (and forthcoming javax.time) provide a Duration class, and JPA providers such as [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org) provide persistence for them out of the box without the need to play around with conversions.

Comment: For what I know, also java has a duration class and for the moment I just want to stick to Hibernate :)

Comment: The Joda Time project also has it's own support classes for Hibernate - you can probably use this if your JPA provider is Hibernate, but I'm not sure. See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html

Comment: FWIW javax.xml.datatype.Duration is intended for use within XML docs, not for serious treatment of time.