# Insert Date into a database from java

Tags: java, database, date

I have a database where I have a field that is type DATE and I want to make a function in java to insert values in the database.
The problem is that when I insert a Date I get a NULL in the database DATE field.

I'm doing this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null:
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DB1(print_date) values(?)";
stmt.setDate(1, database.getPrintDate());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

How can I insert the PrintDate which is DATE type in the database? Thank you

Comment: Which database are you using?  Are you **positive** that database.getPrintDate() returns != null?

Comment: are you using java.util.Date or java.sql.Date?

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong in your code. And since it doesn't throw an exception, I can only assume that database.getPrintDate() must be null. Have you tried adding another column and stmt.setInt(2,1); to see if that works or if it is a Date issue?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the output of `System.out.println(database.getPrintDate());`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date - Insert into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081234/java-date-insert-into-database)