# How to insert DATE type in PostgreSql using Java?

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a column of date type (daterecord) in PostgreSql and jdatechooser component in java (dateChooser). I am trying to insert the selected date into my database with this initial code:

```
Date daterec = dateChooser.getDate();
String sql= "INSERT INTO date values (?)";
pst.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setDate(1, daterec);
pst.execute();
```

..but I know my setDate code is wrong..please help what to do?

Comment: What do you mean with "*my setDate code is wrong*"? This looks fine to me (although it's better to use `executeUpdate()` instead of `execute()` in this case)

Comment: What is the stacktrace? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Postgres does not have any `daterecord` data type amongst [its date-time types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date - Insert into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081234/java-date-insert-into-database)

Comment: the code looks fine (although `date` is a horrible name for a table) - what is the exact problem you have? Please [edit] your question and add the complete `create table` statement for your table

Answer (score 0):

i can tell you how to insert a date record into a mysql table by using the Datechooser control..it is how i do it..so it may differ from your point of view

```
public void getdate() {
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String s=df.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
    jLabel1.setText(""+s);
}

public void insert(){
    try{
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/<database_name>","root","<db password>"); 
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String query="insert into test  values('"+jLabel1.getText()+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insert successful");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error in connectivity");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do **not** concatenate user input into a SQL string. Use a `PreparedStatement` and never pass a `date` value as a plain string.