# insert date in oracle database via jsp java

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I've searched stackoverflow but did not found the solution (at least the way I want it).

I have a JSP page which calls a Java method to insert a date into Oracle database.
It passes a String.
The problem, how to build the string to execute the insert?

```
String myInsert = "INSERT INTO table_name 
  values (..., to_date(<<Java variable name>>, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm'), ....);
```

where Java variable name refers to a variable of type String.
I want to let Oracle to the job, not necessarily using SimpleDateFormat, if it's possible. So, should I use '' or " "
Youre help would be very much appreciated

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date - Insert into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081234/java-date-insert-into-database). Focus on [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1081242/642706). And please **search StackOverflow before posting**. I found that Answer in the *first hit* of a search for "java date insert".

Answer (score 0):

You should use a PreparedStatement along with its setDate function and not deal with date to string conversions yourself.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)

```
String myInsert="INSERT INTO table_name values(...?)";
PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(myInsert);
ps.setDate(1,<<java variable name>>);
...
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It says: ORA 00984: column not allowed here, I think, because of date...

Comment: Mmhhh, post your new query, are you sure it's not the placeholders are in the wrong place?